# In dnspython, given the DNS IP, how to get the DNS zone name

Tags: python, sockets, dns, network-programming, dnspython

Using the `dnspython` library, I have this simple code, given the DNS IP, I canquery a domain name. I need to get the zone name of the DNS server. For example, if instead of `8.8.8.8` I have a private IP `192.168.4.5` for zone named `com` and the server in question is `a.com`.

How can I get the `com` as a result of a query for my zone's DNS IP?

```
import dns.resolver

resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']

def myQuery(domain, records):
    for r in records:
        try:
            response = resolver.query(domain, r)
            for rData in response:
                    domainIP = str(rData)
                    print(domainIP)
                    break # we only need one IP
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

myQuery("google.com","A")
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're after a reverse IP lookup.

You have the IP but you want the name.  If so, you're looking for a PTR type record (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).  PTR records look like this:

5.4.168.192.in-addr.arpa.

You don't have to know that as there's a dns-python helper function called reversername that will generate those names from an IP address for you.  Here's an example of a reverse IP lookup of 8.8.8.8:

```
>>> from dns import reversename, resolver
>>> 
>>> rev_name = reversename.from_address('8.8.8.8')
>>> reversed_dns = str(resolver.query(rev_name,"PTR")[0])
>>> print reversed_dns
google-public-dns-a.google.com.
```

In order to get it to work on your private server, you need to make sure either you or your system is adding/creating PTR records when registering your machines with DNS.  Assuming you have PTR records in your DNS then this should work for you:

```
from dns import reversename, resolver
rev_name = reversename.from_address('192.168.4.5')
reversed_dns = str(resolver.query(rev_name,"PTR")[0])
print(reversed_dns)
```

Comment: I get this error: `Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple-test.py", line 3, in <module>
    reversed_dns = str(resolver.query(rev_name,"PTR")[0])
  File "/usr/local/bin/code/myclient/dns/resolver.py", line 1132, in query
    raise_on_no_answer, source_port)
  File "/usr/local/bin/code/myclient/dns/resolver.py", line 1051, in query
    raise NXDOMAIN(qnames=qnames_to_try, responses=nxdomain_responses)
dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN: The DNS query name does not exist: 3.56.168.192.in-addr.arpa.`

Comment: That indicates that the DNS server you're querying doesn't have a PTR record for that IP.  As I mentioned, in order for this to work, you need to make sure you have PTR records created in the in-addr.arpa zone of your DNS server.